# Datalist not displaying image from database

Tags: asp.net

My database table contains the image file path I am trying to display that image through a datalist control but the image not displayed the path who displayed

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Answer (score 0):

you image path must be in Relative Path format e.g '~/images/abc.png' Now It will work. Thumps Up.
http://www.aspdotnet-example.blogspot.com